# Meaning of "it will not do to risk a fainting fit."

Tags: expressions, collocations

Below is a passage from *Jane Eyre*:

> ‘You don’t turn sick at the sight of blood?’
>
> ‘I think I shall not: I have never been tried yet.’
>
> I felt a thrill while I answered him; but no coldness, and no faintness.
>
> ‘Just give me your hand,’ he said: **‘it will not do** to risk a fainting fit.’

Those are Mr Rochester and Jane Eyre speaking. I'm struggling to understand the meaning of the words in bold. "It will not do to [verb]" seems to be a collocation, but I can't seem to find its meaning. All I've found are expressions like "That'll do (fine)" or "That will not do!", but those seem unrelated (or I can't see the relation, anyway).

What does Mr Rochester mean by *‘it will not do to risk a fainting fit’*?

Also, similar sentences to see how this collocation works would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[One of the many meanings of *do* is "be appropriate, be suitable".](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/do1_1)

*It won't do to X* or *X won't do* is [an idiomatic way of saying "X is not appropriate/suitable/satisfactory"](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/won-t-do-wouldn-t-do-doesn-t-do).

So yes, actually "That will do fine" or "That will not do!" is in fact related - it just means "That will be perfectly acceptable" or "That will not be suitable!"  Some examples of ways in which you might use this kind of phrase:

> It won't do to be seen in those old clothes.  (that is, it *won't be appropriate* to be seen in those old clothes)
>
> I see you have some rubber boots; those will do for our fishing trip. (that is, those boots *will be suitable*)
>
> How much money do you have on you?  Twenty dollars?  That'll do.  (that is, twenty dollars *is sufficient*)

Answer (score 0):

> it will not do

means the same as "it is unacceptable":

> ‘Just give me your hand,’ he said: ‘it **is unacceptable** to risk a fainting fit.’